# pip remains on the old version after updating

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I keep trying to update pip with:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

It seems to complete fine but when I run `pip --version` its still running the old version (19.0.3 vs 19.3). I'm using pycharm on Windows 10.

I'm trying to install pandas and I've read the issue I'm getting can be solved by updating pip and setuptools.

I saw some suggestions to delete the pip folder. So I went to Python38/Lib/site-packages and found 3 pip folders. pip, pip-19.0.3-py3.8egg. There was a 19.3 folder I deleted already.
If I delete the 19.0.3 folder I get an error running pip commands saying:

```
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 19.3 (c:\users\jxdwa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==
19.0.3'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3251, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3234, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3263, in _initialize_master
_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_require
ments
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "C:\Users\Jxdwa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: suggest to make sure `pip` is the `pip` you mean to use (belonging to `python38` version)

Comment: Is the old version being uninstalled? If so there's a chance you have two instances of PIP installed in different locations. Try removing one or uninstalling both then reinstalling.